# Creating an object inside a dll on heap to use in other dll calls

Tags: c#, c++, dll, heap-memory, void-pointers

### Background

I have a c# program that calls a c++ dll containing the code to create a model(Net type) and use the model to evaluate an image. As the dll function currently contains the code to load the model, the time taken to run this function is too long the for the task of evaluating a live feed.

I would like to only have to create the model once from a dll call and then pass a pointer to the model to an evaluate function, thus removing the overhead of loading the model from file.

### Attempt

I have attempted to create a function that is passed a void **, creates a model on heap and points the passed void ** to it. This would allow me to pass the pointer to other functions within the dll and create a model object from the memory on heap.

I cannot get this to work and, although it seems to me like it should be possible, i am not sure if it is.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this or on how to fix my code would be appreciated, thanks.

### Error

Attempted to read or write protected memory at "loadNet()"

c++/dll code

```
void loadNet(void **np)
{
    String modelFile = "graph.pb";
    Net *net;
    net = (Net *)malloc(sizeof(Net));
    *net = readNetFromTensorflow(modelFile)

    *np = &net;
}

extern "C"{
    DLLEXPORT void loadNet(void **);
}
```

c# code to call dll

```
[DllImport("Project5.dll")]
public static extern unsafe void loadNet(void **np);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    unsafe
    {
        void *np;
        loadNet(&np);

        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("2.png");

        BitmapData bmpData = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,img.Width, 
                             img.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                             img.PixelFormat);
        Results results = evalImgGest2(bmpData.Scan0,&np);
        img.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        Console.WriteLine(results.five);
        Console.WriteLine(results.fist);
        Console.WriteLine(results.index);
    }         
}
```

### Updates

```
net = (Net *)malloc(sizeof(Net)); // is causing error 
Net *net = new Net(); // replacing with this removes error
```

Comment: I would say, the problem can be in `*net = readNertFromTensorflow(modelFile)`. What is the `Net` type? It is a structure or a class?

Comment: The Total commander has a similar way of creating definitions in you can look at that. The difference is, that the initialisation is returned as return value: `HANDLE __stdcall OpenArchive(tOpenArchiveData *archiveData)` in your case: `void *loadNet()`.

Comment: the Net type is a class

Comment: This `*np = &net;` assignation of class is not a good idea. There can be the problem. And how is defined the `readNertFromTensorflow`. This can be another problem.

Comment: readNetFromTensorflow is from the opencv library used in the dll

Comment: commenting out the `*net = readNetFromTensorflow(modelFile);` stops the error from occurring. I guess this means i am saving the model to heap incorrectly.